# Can we use the same pair of public and private keys for more than two communications at the same time?

Tags: cryptography

Can we use same pair of public and private keys for more than two communications at the same time?

Or do we need to get a different pair of keys for different communications (at the same time)?

For example:
There are 3 persons: A B C.
Now should A share the same public key with both B and C or should it generate two pairs of public and private keys and give one public key to each?

Comment: I reformulated and reformatted the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The same key pair can be used for all communications but to make it secure we need the peers to derive the common key for each specific conversation. Example of such method is TLS protocol where the common key for each conversation is created using the same server peer key pair.